# Advanced insert Into XML files

Tags: xml, powershell

## Problem Statement

Please take a look at [this previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639945/powershell-advanced-insert-into-xml-files-only-if-vatmode-tag-is-missing). I'm trying to achieve something similar to it, but this time with more advanced criteria.

Put simply, I need to add a child nodes (XML tags) under their parents `<NETTOTAL>`. The child node text content consists of 8-digit numbers extracted from the same XML file. Those numbers are being extracted and stored in an array for later processing as you will see in the script below.

#### About the Script

The existing script works, but I suspect that the loop logic is wrong. I need it to pick and place one XML tag with it's corresponding 8-digit number under each parent, not pick, loop, and place the same exact child.

### Original XML File Contents

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<EXPORT>
    <IMPORTMODEL>NEX</IMPORTMODEL>
    <SESSION>1000061</SESSION>
    <CUSTORDERS>
        <RECORD CODE="NX0100103">
            <VATMODE>X</VATMODE>
            <INPUTDATE>26/07/2017</INPUTDATE>
            <NETTOTAL>97.40</NETTOTAL>
            <DOCLINES>
                <LINE>
                    <LINETYPE>M</LINETYPE>
                    <ITEMDESC>Salesperson: firstName1 lastName1 (43700006)</ITEMDESC>
                </LINE>
            </DOCLINES>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD CODE="NX0100104">
            <VATMODE>X</VATMODE>
            <INPUTDATE>26/07/2017</INPUTDATE>
            <NETTOTAL>38.20</NETTOTAL>
            <DOCLINES>
                <LINE>
                    <LINETYPE>M</LINETYPE>
                    <ITEMDESC>Salesperson: firstName2 lastName2 (43100015)</ITEMDESC>
                </LINE>
            </DOCLINES>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD CODE="NX0100105">
            <VATMODE>X</VATMODE>
            <INPUTDATE>26/07/2017</INPUTDATE>
            <NETTOTAL>63.00</NETTOTAL>
            <DOCLINES>
                <LINE>
                    <LINETYPE>M</LINETYPE>
                    <ITEMDESC>Salesperson: firstName3 lastName3 (43100014)</ITEMDESC>
                </LINE>
            </DOCLINES>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD CODE="NX0100106">
            <VATMODE>X</VATMODE>
            <INPUTDATE>26/07/2017</INPUTDATE>
            <NETTOTAL>55.00</NETTOTAL>
            <DOCLINES>
                <LINE>
                    <LINETYPE>M</LINETYPE>
                    <ITEMDESC>Salesperson: firstName2 lastName2 (43100015)</ITEMDESC>
                </LINE>
            </DOCLINES>
        </RECORD>
    </CUSTORDERS>
</EXPORT>
```

### Desired Goal

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<EXPORT>
    <IMPORTMODEL>NEX</IMPORTMODEL>
    <SESSION>1000061</SESSION>
    <CUSTORDERS>
        <RECORD CODE="NX0100103">
            <VATMODE>X</VATMODE>
            <INPUTDATE>26/07/2017</INPUTDATE>
            <NETTOTAL>97.40</NETTOTAL>
            <SALESMAN>43700006</SALESMAN>
            <DOCLINES>
                <LINE>
                    <LINETYPE>M</LINETYPE>
                    <ITEMDESC>Salesperson: firstName1 lastName1 (43700006)</ITEMDESC>
                </LINE>
            </DOCLINES>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD CODE="NX0100104">
            <VATMODE>X</VATMODE>
            <INPUTDATE>26/07/2017</INPUTDATE>
            <NETTOTAL>38.20</NETTOTAL>
            <SALESMAN>43100015</SALESMAN>
            <DOCLINES>
                <LINE>
                    <LINETYPE>M</LINETYPE>
                    <ITEMDESC>Salesperson: firstName2 lastName2 (43100015)</ITEMDESC>
                </LINE>
            </DOCLINES>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD CODE="NX0100105">
            <VATMODE>X</VATMODE>
            <INPUTDATE>26/07/2017</INPUTDATE>
            <NETTOTAL>63.00</NETTOTAL>
            <SALESMAN>43100014</SALESMAN>
            <DOCLINES>
                <LINE>
                    <LINETYPE>M</LINETYPE>
                    <ITEMDESC>Salesperson: firstName3 lastName3 (43100014)</ITEMDESC>
                </LINE>
            </DOCLINES>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD CODE="NX0100106">
            <VATMODE>X</VATMODE>
            <INPUTDATE>26/07/2017</INPUTDATE>
            <NETTOTAL>55.00</NETTOTAL>
            <SALESMAN>43100015</SALESMAN>
            <DOCLINES>
                <LINE>
                    <LINETYPE>M</LINETYPE>
                    <ITEMDESC>Salesperson: firstName2 lastName2 (43100015)</ITEMDESC>
                </LINE>
            </DOCLINES>
        </RECORD>
    </CUSTORDERS>
</EXPORT>
```

### Script

```bsh
$xmlFilesLocation = "C:\XML_dumping"

cd $xmlFilesLocation

$netTotalRegEx = "(<NETTOTAL>\d{1,30}\.\d{1,2}<\/NETTOTAL>)"
$salesManRegEx = "(<SALESMAN>\d{8}<\/SALESMAN>)"

$beginTag = "`t`t`t<SALESMAN>"
$endTag = "</SALESMAN>"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $xmlFilesLocation -Filter *.xml

$numberOfFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $xmlFilesLocation -Filter *.xml | Measure-Object).Count

# First, loop through all files separately to check if <SALESMAN>[code]</SALESMAN> exists, and skip if true
for ($i=1; $i -le $numberOfFiles; $i++) {
    $content = (Get-Content $files[$i - 1] -Raw)

    # Skip file if <SALESMAN>[code]</SALESMAN> is detected in it
    if ($content -match $salesManRegEx) { break }
}

# Then, loop through all files (again) separately to check if <SALESMAN>[code]</SALESMAN> is missing, and process if true
for ($j=1; $j -le $numberOfFiles; $j++) {
    $content = (Get-Content $files[$j - 1] -Raw)

    # If <SALESMAN>[code]</SALESMAN> is missing in the file
    if ($content -notmatch $salesManRegEx) {
        $contentArray = @()

        # Hold all the content, but split from the brackets
        $contentArray = $content
        $contentArray = $contentArray.Split("()")
        # Now split by line to extract the salesman codes into an array.
        # Example: [43700006, 43100015, 43100014, 43100015]
        $contentArray = $contentArray.Split("")

        for ($k=1; $k -le $contentArray.Length; $k++) {
            # if the salesman code is found...
            if ($contentArray[$k] -match "^\d{8}$") {
                if ($content -notmatch $salesManRegEx) {
                    # Construct the full tag
                    $fullSalesManTag = $beginTag + $contentArray[$k] + $endTag

                    # ...then replace in $content the regular expression with $fullSalesManTag and insert it directly underneath NETTOTAL line
                    $content= [regex]::Replace($content, $netTotalRegEx, ('$1' + "`n" + "$fullSalesManTag"))

                    $content | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 $files[$j - 1]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Current Output

The output is clearly showing that it's only adding the last element in the array index. That's when the loop has ended. I understand why this is happening, but I can't wrap my head around a solution to correct the logic.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<EXPORT>
    <IMPORTMODEL>NEX</IMPORTMODEL>
    <SESSION>1000061</SESSION>
    <CUSTORDERS>
        <RECORD CODE="NX0100103">
            <VATMODE>X</VATMODE>
            <INPUTDATE>26/07/2017</INPUTDATE>
            <NETTOTAL>97.40</NETTOTAL>
            <SALESMAN>43700006</SALESMAN>
            <DOCLINES>
                <LINE>
                    <LINETYPE>M</LINETYPE>
                    <ITEMDESC>Salesperson: firstName1 lastName1 (43700006)</ITEMDESC>
                </LINE>
            </DOCLINES>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD CODE="NX0100104">
            <VATMODE>X</VATMODE>
            <INPUTDATE>26/07/2017</INPUTDATE>
            <NETTOTAL>38.20</NETTOTAL>
            <SALESMAN>43700006</SALESMAN>
            <DOCLINES>
                <LINE>
                    <LINETYPE>M</LINETYPE>
                    <ITEMDESC>Salesperson: firstName2 lastName2 (43100015)</ITEMDESC>
                </LINE>
            </DOCLINES>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD CODE="NX0100105">
            <VATMODE>X</VATMODE>
            <INPUTDATE>26/07/2017</INPUTDATE>
            <NETTOTAL>63.00</NETTOTAL>
            <SALESMAN>43700006</SALESMAN>
            <DOCLINES>
                <LINE>
                    <LINETYPE>M</LINETYPE>
                    <ITEMDESC>Salesperson: firstName3 lastName3 (43100014)</ITEMDESC>
                </LINE>
            </DOCLINES>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD CODE="NX0100106">
            <VATMODE>X</VATMODE>
            <INPUTDATE>26/07/2017</INPUTDATE>
            <NETTOTAL>55.00</NETTOTAL>
            <SALESMAN>43700006</SALESMAN>
            <DOCLINES>
                <LINE>
                    <LINETYPE>M</LINETYPE>
                    <ITEMDESC>Salesperson: firstName2 lastName2 (43100015)</ITEMDESC>
                </LINE>
            </DOCLINES>
        </RECORD>
    </CUSTORDERS>
</EXPORT>
```

Comment: @kjhughes The question ["Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/1630171) is certainly related I don't agree that it's a duplicate. This question is about re-inserting information from an XML file as new nodes, but not necessarily about doing it via regular expressions.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Anyone trying to parse XML with regex needs to be told to use a real XML parser (as you've done below +1, btw), and further discussion really ought to be squelched because this topic has been beaten to death.  I could close against any number of questions, but the one I chose, although not a specific duplicate, is a good general explanation for the general misconception behind this whole class of misguided questions.

Comment: I certainly agree with educating people about why attempts to parse XML with regular expressions is misguided. I just prefer telling people what to *do* in addition to telling them what *not* to do. The question describes a rather straightforward, answerable problem, with an honest (although misguided) attempt to solve it, so I believe an actual answer is going to be more helpful than a mere discussion (however thorough) of why the original approach was misguided.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Closing the question doesn't detract from your admirable and helpful answer, but I'll yield and leave this open as you wish.  Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Do not parse XML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1630171). Every time you do a rainbow unicorn dies.

But seriously, in most cases regular expressions are the wrong tool for working with XML files. If you're interested, the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/1630171) (thanks to kjhughes for the link) discuss the issues with the regex approach in depth.

Use a proper XML parser and a couple [XPath expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471.aspx) to extract the salesperson ID and add it as a new node:

```
$xmlfile = 'C:\path\to\your.xml'

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $xmlfile

$xml.SelectNodes('//RECORD') | ForEach-Object {
  $id = $_.SelectSingleNode('.//ITEMDESC').'#text' -replace '.*\((\d+)\).*', '$1'

  $sibling = $_.SelectSingleNode('./NETTOTAL')

  $node = $xml.CreateElement('SALESMAN')
  $node.InnerText = $id
  $_.InsertAfter($node, $sibling)
}

$xml.Save($xmlfile)
```

Comment: Beat me to it :-) regex is definitely not the answer

Comment: Thank you for providing the correct method to parse XML files and for the enlightenment.